# Creating a global helper method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 7
Ruby 3.1
```

I would like to add a global helper method, just like devise's current_user

I understand that the current_use helper is done through the application controller, so I tried modifying app/controllers/application_controller.rb:

```
helper_method :my_test

def my_test
  5
end
```

But when I do:

```
rails c
```

If I do:

```
my_test
```

I get the following error message:

(irb):2:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method` my_test' for main:Object (NameError)

Comment: There's a lot of missing context, but when you open irb you're not in a controller context. Helpers are (primarily) for views, which operate in the context of a controller. If you want a _method_ exposed "globally" that's a library/utility, not a helper.

Comment: I would put the helper method in its own file. Rails should just auto require that file if it is in your project directory.

Comment: If you want it to behave like devise's `current_user` then you have accomplished that.
As long as all of your controllers inherit from `ApplicationController` then that method will be available in all controllers and all views.
However, it is still a controller helper, so it's not available in the interactive Rails console without some extra work (which you can look up).

Comment: You can't use `current_user` either in a rails console like that.

Comment: @DaveNewton the context in IRB is actually an integration test which is pretty wild. You can access it via `app` and call for example path helpers on.

Comment: @max Sure, but that’s not the point I was making or what I said—what I said was that *helpers* are primarily for views. I was correcting/explaining terminology.